# Custom progress bar using image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on a custom progress bar that will display a part of an image based on percentage value. My idea was to have two images, original and b&w version. I am displaying the b&w and on top of that I'm cropping, based on percentage, the original image. Is working great but from top to bottom.

I would like to ask, there is any way to make the original image to "grow" from bottom to top?

Below is a sample of my code until now:

```
    UIImageView *imgDefViewGray = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 85, 60, 60)];
    imgDefViewGray.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"castle-gray.png"];
    [self addSubview:imgDefViewGray];

    UIImageView *imgDefView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 85, 60, 60)];
    imgDefView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"castle.png"];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 60, **50**);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imgDefView.image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    imgDefView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 85, 60, **50**)];
    imgDefView.image = img;
    [self addSubview:imgDefView];
```

So, by changing the value on **Bold**(double asterisks), I have achieved to crop the original image as much as I want but with direction top->bottom. I would like it bottom->top.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I've figured out to get the result that I want. Below is my solution to my problem. I hope anyone in the future who will face or want the same find it useful.

```
    UIImageView *imgDefViewGray = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 85, 60, 60)];
    imgDefViewGray.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"castle-gray.png"];//60x60 b&w image

    UIImage originalImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"castle.png"];//60x60 original image
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, originalImg.size.height-scaleDefence), 60 , scaleDefence);//scaleDefence is just a float variable that converts current percentage value to px.

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImg CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *croppedImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    UIImageView *imgDefView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, originalImg.size.height-scaleDefence, 60, scaleDefence)];//dynamically changing y-axis depending on cropped image's height.
    imgDefView.image = croppedImg;

    [imgDefViewGray addSubview:imgDefView];//make original image part of b&w
    [self addSubview:imgDefViewGray];//finally add the result to the view
```

Comment: excellent piece of code. I wanna ask how do you calculate the scaleDefence variable? Is it like 10% of image height or something?

Comment: Hello @AkashMalhotra. Thank you for nice words. As said in code block, scaleDefence is the conversation of current defence to a float number that used do cover appropriate area of image. As you've correctly mentioned is the area of original image height. If current defence is 10% then, will cover 10% of original image height. If you found my solution useful please up vote or mark it as accepted. Will really help me. Happy coding :)

Comment: I used your code in both background thread as well as main, but i cant seem to properly show the animation, I mean it directly shows the updated colored image overlapped rather than slowly updating it from B/w to color. I used wait(), sleep() but to no avail. Can you help?

Comment: Hello @AkashMalhotra, please help me to understand, you are trying to create a splash animation screen or something?

Comment: no i am trying to show the colored image being overlapped on the B/W image while the selector runs in background

Comment: What if you call the corresponding method using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval? Each time increase 'scaleDefence' as many as you like until maximum size (in this case is 60).